# Cyrillic characters replaced by question mark in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with Cyrillic characters. In my create procedure script, there is

```
select
    ...
    case 
        when aug.IsGroup = 0 then N'Нет' 
        else N'Да' 
    end as IsGroupFact
    ...
```

There are all variables which related to Cyrillic characters contains in `nvarchar(max)`.

After adding `.sql` file of stored procedure into the project and pushing it to the main CI/CD branch, the characters becomes to the

```
select
    ...
    case 
        when aug.IsGroup = 0 
            then N'???' 
            else N'??' 
    end as IsGroupFact
    ...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Doesn't sound like an SQL Server issue but some encoding going wrong or being translated wrongly somewhere along your tool chain. It just happens to be a file with code for SQL Server but likely happens to all files.

Comment: What encoding are you saving `.sql` files with? I suspect it's neither UTF-8 nor UTF-16.